# How to chain lambdas to a resulting lambda in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, lambda, chaining

... or the equivalent of `java.util.Function.andThen()`

In Java

```
Function<String, String> add1 = string -> string + "1";
Function<String, String> add2 = string -> string + "2";
Function<String, Strint> add12 = add1.andThen(add2);
```

`add12.apply("")` returns `"12"`

How would I write it in Kotlin?

```
val add1 = { string:String -> string + "1" }
val add2 = { string:String -> string + "2" }
val add12 = ?
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The feature you're looking for is called *function composition*. As far as I can tell, it doesn't come built-in to Kotlin (would love to be corrected on this). But it's very easy to write as an extension function.

```
infix fun<A, B, C> ((B) -> C).compose(that: (A) -> B): (A) -> C =
  { this(that(it)) }
```

Now we can write

```
val add1 = { string:String -> string + "1" }
val add2 = { string:String -> string + "2" }

println((add2 compose add1)("3")) // Prints "312"
```

I write `compose` to use right-to-left composition, more in line with the way mathematical functions work.

Comment: So you mean Kotlin does not have native support for this then? That's a pity.

Comment: You could update the answer to also include left-to-right example for extra points

Comment: This is five years old, but it looks like the original philosophy with the Kotlin standard library is that this is too specific to certain programming styles to include: https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/function-composition-in-standard-library/1683

Comment: It's a crying shame. I've seen that argument made in several programming languages (Lisp coders, of all people, seem to be of the opinion function composition isn't important enough to include). It should be a staple in every language, if you ask me.

Comment: I personally don't miss it at all, but it seems kind of weird to omit because it's so trivial, yet they get so very specific with all their variations of ways to fold a collection.

Comment: left-to-right: `fun <A, B, C> ((A) -> B).andThen(that: (B) -> C): (A) -> C = { that(this(it)) }`

Comment: Probably this is because we don't pass function references that much in Kotlin. It feels unnatural, at least to me. `doSomething { add2(add1(it)) }` is shorter, much more readable and very clear about the operation ordering than `doSomething(::add2 compose ::add1)`. But maybe I miss good examples where lambdas aren't sufficient.

Comment: You don't pass function references unless you need to, if the function is supplied from the outside you have no other choice, the other solutions hardcode what for me are external variables, unlike this solution.

Answer (score 1):

Granted, this is not exactly what you're looking for, because you can't store a composed function this way in a variable, but you can chain the results of functions using `run` if the functions themselves don't have the parameter as a receiver:

```
fun print(string: String) {
    println(add1(string).run(add2))
}

// or

fun print(string: String) {
    println(string.run(add1).run(add2))
}
```

Since `run` is an inline function, it doesn't add a wrapper object around each function.

The `let` function will have the exact same effect. This is because when you pass something other than a lambda to a higher order function, it doesn't matter if the first parameter is a receiver or not. They are treated as the same signature.

Comment: You are not answering my question, but maybe I was not clear, will update.

Comment: No, I understand that I'm not as mentioned in my first sentence. Just offering an alternative that might possibly work depending on the reason why you were looking to compose functions in the first place. It might be helpful to someone that searches and finds this question and just wants to chain some functions, with no need to store the combined function in a variable.

Answer (score 1):

If you are that familiar with Java functions and/or want to use them, you are still open to do that (using `java.util.function.Function`):

```
val add1 : Function<String, String> = Function { "${it}1"}
val add2 : Function<String, String> = Function { "${it}2"}
val add12: Function<String, String> = add1.andThen(add2)
```

If I wanted to have something similar in Kotlin, I would probably just go for what also Tenfour04 showed, i.e. use either `let` or `run`:

```
val add1 : (String) -> String = { "${it}1"}
val add2 : (String) -> String = { "${it}2"}
val add12 : (String) -> String = { it.let(add1).let(add2) } // or: { add1(it).let(add2) }
```

If you compare the two you only spare something, if you omit the type, but it's still clear enough what gets composed.

Of course you can implement your own `compose` or `andThen`-functions. However, if you don't mind using an additional library, you may rather be interested in [Arrow](https://arrow-kt.io/docs/core/) where lots of functional use-cases are already supported.